# Administrator account appears not to have all privileges

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 machine, where I have enabled the local "Administrator" account. When I log in as this local Administrator I still cannot do everything I want to do. There are still settings that are disabled.

What do I possible need to look at in order to make my Administrator account in to a real super user account? Is there some hidden setting in Windows 7 that prohibits the Administrator from really being an administrator?

It has been suggested that I need to "run as administrator" those programs where I need administrator privileges. But how do I do I do this with the control panel?

Comment: This is functioning as designed. The administrator account does not always have full rights. It has the **option** to get them. You will actively need to decide to do that. E.g. click yes on the UAC prompt, or select a program, right click on it and use the "Run as administrator" option.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/592421/windows-7-administrator-user-doesnt-have-admin-rights?rq=1

Comment: Now `Administrator` is not the highest. There are more privileged accounts such as `SYSTEM` and `TrustedInstaller`.

Comment: How do I "run as administrator" with the control panel?

Comment: What particular options are not available?