# Cannot install *any* software on Windows 8 PC

Tags: windows-8

My niece asked me to have a look at some problems on her Windows 8 PC. On of her points was that she thought there is/are virus(es) on it. So the first thing I tried was install Avast:

> "The installer cannot extract VPS files to [temp path]"

Then AVG:

> "Unable to extract setup contents. [...] make sure you have administrator right. (can not create temp folder archive)

Her login account is an administrator's. Next I tried Firefox:

> "Can not create temp folder archive"

WPS office:

> "error writing temporary file. Make sure your temp folder is valid."

So the returning message is that the temp folder can't be written to. How do I fix this? Can this indeed be caused by a virus? If yes, then I have a chicken-and-egg problem: to fix it I have to install an anti-virus program, but I can't install one until it's fixed.

*(Note: I'm a Windows 7 user myself, and have little experience with Win 8. IMO it's the least intuitive, and therefore the most user-unfriendly OS ever. I didn't even find a way to shut down the computer, go figure. So please bear with me.)*

**edit**
upon request by *and31415*, the result of *icacls %temp%*:

```
C:\Users\Lynn\AppData\Local\Temp NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)  
                             INGEBOUWD\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)  
                             LYNN\Lynn:(OI)(CI)(F)  
                             INGEBOUWD\Gebruikers:(OI)(CI)(RX)  

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

*("ingebouwd" is Dutch for "built-in")*

Comment: Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8), run the following command, and post here the output: `icacls %temp%`

Comment: @and31415 - Info added to question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Try right clicking the installer and click "Run as Administrator"...

Comment: @BigChris - Doesn't help: same messages, probably because she is logged in as administrator already, like I mentioned in the question. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Being logged in as Administrator doesn't mean everything you do has full administrative permissions to the OS. See: http://superuser.com/questions/592421/windows-7-administrator-user-doesnt-have-admin-rights - the same applies to Win 8. But, as you say, it hasn't had an affect, but for your future reference :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your hard drive might be full, so nothing can extract any installers. Can you check for us?

Comment: Can you make a new account with root\admin privileges and try it again?

Comment: If its windows 8, you *should* already have a halfway competent antivirus called windows defender. Assuming that that's been neutralised somehow, you'd seriously want to consider a *offline* virus scan with a livecd. I tend to use the MS one  unfortunately, but I believe kaspersky or sophos have acceptable, free ones

Comment: Oh, and as for not being able to find *anything*, on windows 8, rightswipe, and settings. Windows 8.1 (which is a lot less annoying has the win x shortcut.

Comment: ( You can also just go to Control Panel which still exists just like Windows 7 ).

Comment: As to cghecking for malware or virusses: Do not do that from the OS which you are checking. Boot from a CD or pendrive and scan the system from that.

Answer (score 0):

This may occur due to many reasons like problem with user profile, limited permission to temp folder, or may be due to third party programs.

> **Fix I: Fix Corrupted User Profile:**

To do so simply create a new *User Profile* with '*Administrator*' type and try installing software using the new Administrator account. If it works then delete the old account after backing-up data.
(*Try restarting your system for better result*).

> **Fix II: Change Ownership permission of temp Folder:**

Case A: Take Ownership of temp folder with simple click [Read this Article](http://www.askvg.com/add-take-ownership-option-in-file-folder-context-menu-in-windows-vista/).
Case B: Change Permission of temp folder using this [Guide](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-file-or-folder-manually-in-windows/).
Case C: Working with [TrustedInstaller](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/).

> **Fix III: Changing 'Startup Type' of Windows Installer service:**

To do so open "**service.msc**" as administrator and locate "**Windows Installer**" Service and
double click to open properties.
Change "*Startup Type*" to '*Automatic*'.
Now go to *Recovery* tab and in the *First failure* & *Second failure* select option '*Restart the Service*' and click on *Apply* and then **OK**.

> **Fix IV: If all the above methods does not worked then:**

(i) Try disabling your antivirus and firewall.
(ii) Uninstalling Adobe Acrobat and changing temp folder permissions to default also worked for some users.

(*For better result try restarting your system after each fix or sometimes after cases*)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on a Windows Vista PC after I deinstalled the Avast Premier edition and wanted to install the Avast free version. I did put the avast_free_antivirus_online.exe file in the C:\users\yourname\AppData\local\temp- directory and started the exe from this directory, then the install was succesfull.